# How to show freeow or modal alert?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, prototypejs, alert

I want to show errors using Freeow or Modal alert. The PHP is using AJAX to fill some select input dropdowns. I'm using noConflict and creating one variable for each plugin (Freeow and Modal).

The JavaScript alert works, but the call to show Freeow or Modal doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```php
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./prototype.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript"> var jq = jQuery.noConflict(); </script>
            <script type="text/javascript"> var jm = jQuery.noConflict(); </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../Freeow/jquery.freeow.min.js"></script>


    <?PHP   if ($valid === false) {      ?>
            <script>
                alert("before Freeow call");
                jq("#freeow").freeow("My Title", "Here's a message");
                alert("before modal call");
                jm('#myModal').modal('show');
            </script>
    <?PHP   }   ?>


    <html>
    <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <link href="../bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css"     rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="../bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="../bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.js"       rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="../bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"   rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="../Freeow/style/freeow/freeow.css"        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  >
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="freeow" class="freeow freeow-top-right"></div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You are adding `<script>` tags outside `<html>` tags.

Comment: Why are you including both `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.min.js`? And then AGAIN as CSS links? The `min` means "minimized", which is compacted for faster loading, so having both is redundant. Including `js` as CSS links is just wrong.

Comment: I made the code update but still doesn't work. Please check link: http://www.carvalho.eng.br/contato_bioma/con_create_eng.php

Answer (score 0):

I inspected the JS file [demo.js](http://pjdietz.com/includes/component/jquery-plugins/freeow/demo/demo.js) on [the freeow demo page](http://pjdietz.com/jquery-plugins/freeow/) and compared with the code in your question. As [gre_gor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794749/gre-gor) mentioned, the `<script>` tags are added outside the `<html>` tags. Move those inside the HTML (either in the `<head>` or `<body>` tag) in order to have the JavaScript run properly.

Additionally, the JavaScript code should wait until the document is ready (e.g. after the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event) before trying to utilize the freeow extensions. jQuery's [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) can be used for that.

The major change I added was wrapping the JavaScript to call the freeow method in the following block:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //code here to utilize the freeow extensions
        jq("#freeow").freeow("My Title", "Here's a message");
        //etc...
    });
)(jq);
```

See the demonstration in the snippet below.

```js
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() { //wait until DOM is ready
    console.log("before Freeow call");
    jq("#freeow").freeow("My Title", "Here's a message");
    console.log("before modal call");
    jm('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
})(jq);
```

```html
<script data-require="prototype@*" data-semver="1.7.1+0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="1.9.1" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://web.archive.org/web/20160410115841/http://pjdietz.com/includes/component/jquery-plugins/freeow/jquery.freeow.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://web.archive.org/web/20160410134722/https://pjdietz.com/includes/component/jquery-plugins/freeow/style/freeow/freeow.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jm = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<div id="freeow" class="freeow freeow-top-right"></div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```